# s#arp architecture + command and handler

Tags: s#arp-architecture

This is my first time using S#arp Architecture 2.0 in a project.

There is two folders in tasks project : Commands and CommandHandlers.

I shearch about it and tried to undestand by the cookbook project what do i have to put there. I am imagining that i have to do something like it was before: a "viewToModel" function and a SaveOrUpdate in the IRepository.

Somebody can explain the "Commands and CommandHandlers" or/and give me a good documentation about it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Cookbook wiki? [Using commands?](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture-Cookbook/wiki/Using-commands)

From your questions, I understand you are after some sort of CRUD functionality, in which case going for a command and handler approach might be overkill, just load the entity in your controller, copy values from the form and save it. Using commands is more suited for a [Task based UI](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/) and where there is some behavior you want on the entities.